# Jupyter Notebooks not working - SSL Error on 11 ('51.37.246.55', 57941): [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645)

Tags: python, ssl, unix, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

Hi I am trying to set up a jupyter notebook running on an AWS when I run it and paste in the url in my browser I get a connection error saying my ip address uses an unsupported protocol - `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` and in my terminal I get the following:

```
SSL Error on 11 ('51.37.246.55', 57941): [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:645)
```

I've tried using a 2048 RSA for my `.pem` file and updating my versions of `python` and `openssl` but still not working

Comment: I have just tried to make jupyter point at the right TLS version by adding in import ssl
c.NotebookApp.ssl_options = {
'ssl_version': ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2
}
to my config file but still has not fixed the problem. I changed my ssl.py to point towards this aswell.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information, don't use comments for this purpose.